# Configure JIRA for specific domain not all domains on same server

Tags: jira

I have installed jira on as a service on my server(myhost) on port 8009

Now I am able to access the jira on myhost:8009.

The problem is that I have other domains on the same host(myhost) say  abc.com , xyz.com etc. And jira is available on all the domains as all these domains are on same host (myhost). So abc.com:8009 , xyz.com:8009 ...each domain has jira.

How can I Control this if I want jira on only one domain , not all domains on my host.

Comment: Block 8009 on those domains?

Answer (score 1):

You should identify the IP of your "myhost", and in Tomcat set the Connector's address attribute to that IP.

If you have multiple domains pointing to a single IP, then set Tomcat to listen only on localhost (127.0.0.1), and set up an Apache (or other httpd you fancy) that only listens on the [given domain name](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) and set up a reverse proxy there.